# Scale rotated image to fill HTML5 Canvas using JavaScript trigonometry?

Tags: html, canvas, rotation, trigonometry, cover

Below is the code I am currently using. With `0` rotation, the image is correctly scaled to fill the canvas. (similar to `background-size: cover`, except using JavaScript on a Canvas)

I'm trying to add a rotate feature, with the following features.

1. Keep image centered while rotating. I tried using `width / 2` in `translate`, and then the opposite in `drawImage`, but as you can see the image did not stay centered. I'm not sure if this is a conflict with my earlier `x` and `y` centering code, or if trigonometry is required here?
2. Automatically scale the image further to cover the canvas. These are arbitrary rotations, not 90 degree increments. I don't want to crop any more of the image than necessary to fill the canvas corners. This is much more complex trigonometry than I am used to dealing with.

I think this can be done with `Math.sin` and `Math.cos`, but it's been a very long time since I've used them. I'm especially uncertain about how to achieve #2. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
var image = new Image()
image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FsbT.jpg'

image.onload = function () {
  
  var maxScaleX = canvas.width / image.width
  var maxScaleY = canvas.height / image.height
  scale = maxScaleX > maxScaleY ? maxScaleX : maxScaleY
  
  var width = image.width * scale
  var height = image.height * scale
  var x = (width - canvas.width) / -2
  var y = (height - canvas.height) / -2
  
  var degrees = 30
  
  context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) // reset previous translate and/or rotate
  context.translate(width / 2, height / 2)
  context.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180)
  
  context.drawImage(image, x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width, height)

}
```

```html
<canvas width="350" height="150" style="border: solid 1px black"></canvas>
```

Comment: See this for an answer to your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34689191/3877726

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[+1 to Blindman67's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688514/after-rotate-draw-image-at-correct-position/34689191#34689191) for this to work.

I shortened the code and simplified for my use case. You should be able to just include `function drawBestFit()` into your app and use it to fill any canvas with any loaded image.

For a better understanding of how this works, view [Blindman67's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688514/after-rotate-draw-image-at-correct-position/34689191#34689191) - especially the demonstration snippet at the bottom.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
var image = new Image()
image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FsbT.jpg'

image.onload = function() {

  var degrees = 0

  loop()

  function loop() {
    degrees += .5
    drawBestFit(context, degrees * Math.PI / 180, image)
    requestAnimationFrame(loop)
  }

  function drawBestFit(ctx, angle, image) {
    
    var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(canvas.width, 2) + Math.pow(canvas.height, 2))
    var diagAngle = Math.asin(canvas.height / dist)

    var a1 = ((angle % (Math.PI * 2)) + Math.PI * 4) % (Math.PI * 2)
    if (a1 > Math.PI)
      a1 -= Math.PI
    if (a1 > Math.PI / 2 && a1 <= Math.PI)
      a1 = (Math.PI / 2) - (a1 - (Math.PI / 2))
    
    var ang1 = Math.PI / 2 - diagAngle - Math.abs(a1)
    var ang2 = Math.abs(diagAngle - Math.abs(a1))
    
    var scale1 = Math.cos(ang1) * dist / image.height
    var scale2 = Math.cos(ang2) * dist / image.width
    
    var scale = Math.max(scale1, scale2)
    
    var dx = Math.cos(angle) * scale
    var dy = Math.sin(angle) * scale
    ctx.setTransform(dx, dy, -dy, dx, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
    
    ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2, image.width, image.height)
    
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) // reset transformations when done

  }

}
```

```html
<canvas width="350" height="200" style="border: solid 1px black"></canvas>
```

Comment: Blindman67 has done nice coding and you have done nice redux. Congrats! Here's an [example implementation of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/92y83ybu/) showing all of the image within the viewport.